# Javascript dynamic input fields on a dynamic inputfield

Tags: javascript

I added a field for text input between the 2 Drop downs if Option number 3 is selected, the text box will appear.

This new text box should get numbers from the User and add new text fields under the Element for options.

For example: if the user adds the number 3 in the text box the radio button created, 3 new text boxes will show up under the Element row and look like this:

Option 1 _____________
Option 2 _____________
Option 3 _____________

```js
// Funkcija za pravljenje Elemenata
var i = 0;
var a = 1;
function mojaFunkcija() {
    var type1 = document.getElementById('type1').value;
    var type2 = document.getElementById('type2').value;
    var question = document.getElementById('question').value;
    var counter = 'Element';
    counter+= a;
    var prviElement=document.createElement('span');
    prviElement.textContent= counter + ':' +'  ';
    document.body.appendChild(prviElement);
    var pitanje= document.createElement('span');
    var unos='unos';
    unos += i;
    pitanje.id=unos;
    pitanje.textContent=question + ' ';
    document.body.appendChild(pitanje);
    var tip1 = document.createElement("input");
    var element='element';
    element += i;
    tip1.id=element;
    if (type1=='textbox') {
        tip1.type=type2
    } else {
        tip1.type=type1
    }
    document.body.appendChild(tip1);
    var linija1= document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(linija1);
    var linija2= document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(linija2);
    i++;
    a++;
}

function AddTextBox(elm) {
    var v = elm.value;
    var iCounter = elm.id.replace('type1', '');

    if (v == 'radio') {
        var textbox = document.createElement('input');
        textbox.type = 'text';
        textbox.id = 'txtSecond' + iCounter;
        elm.parentNode.insertBefore(textbox, elm.nextSibling);
    } else {
        //Ovaj kod ce da izbrise Textbox u slucaju da se izabere druga opcija.
        var rmv = document.getElementById('txtSecond' + iCounter);
        if (rmv != undefined) {
            rmv.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pepo.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="basa.js"></script>
    <title>OnlineForms</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <!--Ovaj kod je za Main Page-->
    <Main class="kocka">
        <div align="left">
            <input type="button" class="dropbtn" value="Administration" onClick="window.location.reload();return false;"/>
            &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
            <button class="dropbtn" id="getAllButton">Forms</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div align="left">
            <input type="number" id="key" class="dropbtn"  Placeholder="Type the key value"/>
            <button class="dropbtn" id="getButton"> Search </button> 
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </Main>
    <!--Ovaj kod je za Elemente-->
    <div id="element" class="hide">
            <h1>Element <input type="text" class="dropbtn" id="question" value="" Placeholder="Type your question here"/>
            <select title="ddmenu" class="dropbtn" id="type1" onChange="AddTextBox(this)">
                <option selected disabled hidden value="Please select">Please select</option>
                <option value="textbox">textbox</option>
                <option value="checkbox">checkbox</option>
                <option value="radio">radio button</option>
                </select>
            <select title="ddmenu" class="dropbtn" id="type2">
                <option selected disabled hidden value="Please select">Please select</option>
                <option value="none">none</option>
                <option value="mandatory">mandatory</option>
                <option value="number">numeric</option>
            </select>
            </h1>
        <input type="button"  id="adddugme" class="dropbtn2" value="Add"  onclick="mojaFunkcija()"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="addButton" class='dropbtn'>Save</button>
        </div>
    <br>
    <br>
<div id="status"></div>
    <br>
<div id="status2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing but I do not see the question?

Comment: The question is when you type 3 in the textbox and click add, 3 input box should be added. here only 1 is adding.

Comment: @NendoDTendo , did you checked the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are executing the code only one time.

Put it inside a loop.

Here, I made a loop to execute the same code `x` times where `x` is the number user entered in the form

Check the snippet

```js
var i = 0;
var a = 1;
function mojaFunkcija() {
    var type1 = document.getElementById('type1').value;
    var type2 = document.getElementById('type2').value;
    var question = document.getElementById('question').value;
    var i=0;
    while(i<question){
       var counter = 'Element';
       counter+= a;
       var prviElement=document.createElement('span');
       prviElement.textContent= counter + ':' +'  ';
       document.body.appendChild(prviElement);
       var pitanje= document.createElement('span');
       var unos='unos';
        unos += i;
        pitanje.id=unos;
       pitanje.textContent=(i+1) + ' ';
        document.body.appendChild(pitanje);
        var tip1 = document.createElement("input");
        var element='element';
        element += i;
        tip1.id=element;
        if (type1=='textbox') {
           tip1.type=type2
        } else {
            tip1.type=type1
         }
          document.body.appendChild(tip1);
          var linija1= document.createElement("br");
          document.body.appendChild(linija1);
          var linija2= document.createElement("br");
          document.body.appendChild(linija2);
          i++;
          a++;
       }
     }

function AddTextBox(elm) {
    var v = elm.value;
    var iCounter = elm.id.replace('type1', '');

    if (v == 'radio') {
        var textbox = document.createElement('input');
        textbox.type = 'text';
        textbox.id = 'txtSecond' + iCounter;
        elm.parentNode.insertBefore(textbox, elm.nextSibling);
    } else {
        //Ovaj kod ce da izbrise Textbox u slucaju da se izabere druga opcija.
        var rmv = document.getElementById('txtSecond' + iCounter);
        if (rmv != undefined) {
            rmv.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pepo.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="basa.js"></script>
    <title>OnlineForms</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <!--Ovaj kod je za Main Page-->
    <Main class="kocka">
        <div align="left">
            <input type="button" class="dropbtn" value="Administration" onClick="window.location.reload();return false;"/>
            &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
            <button class="dropbtn" id="getAllButton">Forms</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div align="left">
            <input type="number" id="key" class="dropbtn"  Placeholder="Type the key value"/>
            <button class="dropbtn" id="getButton"> Search </button> 
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </Main>
    <!--Ovaj kod je za Elemente-->
    <div id="element" class="hide">
            <h1>Element <input type="text" class="dropbtn" id="question" value="" Placeholder="Type your question here"/>
            <select title="ddmenu" class="dropbtn" id="type1" onChange="AddTextBox(this)">
                <option selected disabled hidden value="Please select">Please select</option>
                <option value="textbox">textbox</option>
                <option value="checkbox">checkbox</option>
                <option value="radio">radio button</option>
                </select>
            <select title="ddmenu" class="dropbtn" id="type2">
                <option selected disabled hidden value="Please select">Please select</option>
                <option value="none">none</option>
                <option value="mandatory">mandatory</option>
                <option value="number">numeric</option>
            </select>
            </h1>
        <input type="button"  id="adddugme" class="dropbtn2" value="Add"  onclick="mojaFunkcija()"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="addButton" class='dropbtn'>Save</button>
        </div>
    <br>
    <br>
<div id="status"></div>
    <br>
<div id="status2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve. It seems you're already able to reference the inputbox you want the value from because you're removing it in your `AddTextBox` function. In which case you can use similar code to loop depending on that value. Something like this:

```
var cnt = document.getElementById('txtSecond' + iCounter);
if (cnt != undefined && Number.isInteger(parseInt(cnt.value))) {
  // loop to create options
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Read about the Conditional (Ternary) Operator

then simplify your js:

```
option ? option1 : option2
```

as for the display, I would use:

```
if (option === 'option1'){
  $('option2).hide() // or show
}
```

a little jquery in there, and so forth.

Comment: jQuery is not tagged. Please confirm if OP is fine adding libraries before using them

Comment: willing to help but his coding style is way off, my eyes hurt